# how to fetch a SQLtable to my JSP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

how to fetch a SQL table to my JSP without using JavaScript or ajax

i want all the code in JSP

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%
       //i need to write the code here
    %>

</body>
</html>
```

note : i have created the save method in spring and hibernate but i don't know how to fetch the data

Answer (score 0):

```
   Add this tag 

    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>  

   // then DB details

 <sql:setDataSource
        var="myDS"
        driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName"
        user="root" password="password"
    />
    //Your query
    <sql:query var="listDetails"   dataSource="${myDS}" > SELECT * FROM TableName ;
     </sql:query>

     //Then comes view
     <c:forEach var="listDetails" items="${listDetails.rows}">
      <tr>
       <td><c:out value="${listDetails.id}" /></td>
      </tr>
     </c:forEach>
```